# How to fix the number of gridlines in X-Axis as label are too condensed

Tags: chart.js

How to fix the number of gridlines in X-Axis as label are too condensed.
Example: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html

If we add 60+ Data labels are too condensed, then after some more values axis lines adjust to hide some value in between to show label properly.

[image: Condensed labels]

[image: Adjusted Labels]

Is there a way to control trigger point which adjusts the axis line number ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you defined `xAxes.time.unit: 'month'`, you can define `time.stepSize` as follows.

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  time: {
    unit: 'month',
    stepSize: 2
  },
```

> [`time.stepSize`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#configuration-options): the  number of units between grid lines.

Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for the functionality of the [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

Comment: Just to update i have the value of x-axis as string of "HH:MM:SS", In this case how i can control the stepSize. I don't wants the labels to be steps initially but as values grows past lets say 30 values then gridlines can become 15 to start filling again till 30 and goes on. So 30 becomes the trigger point for ticks to display.

Comment: Appreciate your help, how will this work for string based value ?

Comment: @PazDev: Please provide a runnable code sample that shows what you already have. I will make it easier to come up with a viable solution.